# How to pull a docker template image on a Jenkins slave (AWS/ECR)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In our current setup we have the following Jenkins config.

> Jenkins Master <-- ssh --> Jenkins Slave

So the Jenkins Master is able to connect successfully to the slave. I would like to provide a way so that the slave gets a docker image so we can build using a prebuilt Docker slave. When building the Docker slave locally i can use it, but i seem to hit a wall when i want to pull this Docker build slave from an AWS ECR repository. I seem to be unable to find a way to provide the credentials.

We are using the AWS ECR plugin but this not help in providing details for the ECR pull. (See post http://getmesh.io/Blog/Jenkins+2+Pipeline+101)

Any clue where i can configure the AWS ECR credentials so the Docker Template can be pulled?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware your Jenkins docker slave server should have [awscli installed](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) with a valid AWS secret and key. Once this is completed you can run below command on the Jenkins docker slave server to authenticate:

`aws ecr get-login --region YOUR_REGION --no-include-email | xargs -n 1 -P 10 -I {} bash -c {}`

The command will take the output from the awscli and login on the AWS ECR.

As AWS ECR token expires every 12 hours I have added a cronjob to renew the token every 6 hours.

`0 */6 * * * aws ecr get-login --region YOUR_REGION --no-include-email | xargs -n 1 -P 10 -I {} bash -c {}`

Or as an alternative you can create an internal AWS ECR anonymous proxy from where everyone on your organisation can pull containers. Check [this project for more details](https://github.com/catalinpan/aws-ecr-proxy)